# Generics in java at method level

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, generics, backend

I am new to java. I am trying to debug a code and not able to understand one line.

```
public interface CommandDispatcher {
    <T extends BaseCommand> void registerHandler(Class<T> type, CommandHandlerMethod<T> handler);
    void send(BaseCommand command);
}
```

I know generics but not able to understand below line.

```
 <T extends BaseCommand> void registerHandler(Class<T> type, CommandHandlerMethod<T>)
```

what is  `<T extends BaseCommand>` before `void` also I am not ablr to understand `Class<T>`

Can somebody explain me to understand the above line. Consider `BaseCommand` is an `interface.`

Comment: You want to research *generic methods*. Here is official tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html. Also *bounded type* https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<T extends BaseCommand>` means at the calling side Type T *can* be BaseCommand OR derived from BaseCommand class/interface.

`Class<T>` type means the first argument should be the type of Class T.

```
class Command extends BaseCommand{ 
}
```

then you can call like this

```
registerHandle( Command.class, ...);
```

So that inside implementation one can create instance of Type Command.